# display text based on the value returned by a class binded to a method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am running a loop with each item that has a **button **that has a **class **that is **binded **to a **method**. i want to display a certain text for this button, depending on the **value returned** by the aforementioned **method**

HTML Template

```
<button v-for="(item, index) in items" 
       :key="index" 
       :class="isComplete(item.status)"
> {{ text_to_render_based_on_isComplete_result }} 
</button>
```

Method

```
methods: {
    isComplete(status) {
        let className
        // there is another set of code logic here to determine the value of className. below code is just simplified for this question
        className = logic ? "btn-complete" : "btn-progress"
        return className
    }
}
```

what im hoping to achieve is that if the value of the binded class is equal to "btn-completed", the button text that will be displayed is "DONE". "ON-GOING" if the value is "btn-in-progress"

my first attempt was that i tried to access the `button` for every iteration by using `event.target`. this only returned `undefined`

another option is to make another `method` that will select all of the generated buttons, get the class and change the `textContent` based on the class.

```
newMethod() {
    const completed = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-done')
    const progress= document.getElementsByClassName('btn-progress')

    Array.from(completed).forEach( item => {
        item.textContent = "DONE"
    })

    Array.from(progress).forEach( item => {
        item.textContent = "PROGRESS"
    })
}
```

but this may open another set of issues such as this new method completing before `isComplete()`

Comment: why not just do another method `isCompleteText(item.status)` where you can return the text instead of the class?  As your class is based on the status, your text can be too

Comment: @Pete if you can check the commented code inside the `isComplete()` method, there is an additional code /logic that runs before it can know the `status`. i just simplified it for the sake of this question. the value of `status` is not equal to the parameter given to the method

Comment: it seems like the code snippet is kinda confusing. i will edit it to be more precise

Comment: surely you can use the same logic?  just create sub function that you can call in both?

Comment: If you can't create a sub function to call in both (don't see why that would be the case though) and you really need to base it off your class, then just pass the result  of the function into the new method: `isCompleteText(isComplete(item.status))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved this by returning an array from the `isComplete` method, and accessed the value by using the index.

```
<template>
    <button v-for="(item, index) in items" 
       :key="index" 
       :class="isComplete(item.status)[0]"
       :v-html="isComplete(item.status)[1]"
    >
    </button>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        isComplete(status) {
            let className, buttonText
            // there is another set of code logic here to determine the value of className. below code is just simplified for this question
            if (className == code logic) {
                className = "btn-complete"
                buttonText = "DONE"
            }
            else if (className != code logic) {
                className = "btn-progress"
                buttonText = "ON-GOING"
            }

            return [ className, buttonText ]
        }
    }
}
</script>
```